# Subquery count() for postgres query

Tags: postgresql, gis, aggregate-functions, postgis

I have two tables with web traffic that I am joining and visualizing on a map.

I am trying to write a counter that creates a query result with a count of the number of times a particular IP address shows up in the logs. I think this will take the form of a subquery that returns the count of rows of the specific row the main query is selecting.

When I run the following query, the error I get is `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

```
select
squarespace_ip_addresses.ip,
squarespace_ip_addresses.latitude,
squarespace_ip_addresses.longitude,
st_SetSrid(ST_MAKEPOINT(squarespace_ip_addresses.longitude, squarespace_ip_addresses.latitude), 4326) as geom,
(select count(hostname) from squarespace_logs group by hostname) as counter,
squarespace_logs.referrer
from
squarespace_ip_addresses
left outer join
squarespace_logs
on
squarespace_ip_addresses.ip = squarespace_logs.hostname
```

Something that has been suggested to me is a subquery in a select that filters by the main query output runs that query for every row.

Does anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate the data in a derived table (a subquery in `FROM` clause):

```
select
    a.ip,
    a.latitude,
    a.longitude,
    st_SetSrid(ST_MAKEPOINT(a.longitude, a.latitude), 4326) as geom,    
    c.count,
    l.referrer
from squarespace_ip_addresses a
left join squarespace_logs l on a.ip = l.hostname
left join (
    select hostname, count(*)
    from squarespace_logs
    group by hostname
    ) c on a.ip = c.hostname
```

Comment: So basically this is joining three tables together and gets around the multiple returned columns problem by just accepting that you will get two columns back and joining them.  Is that right?

Comment: Also why is `hostname` necessary in `select hostname, count(*)` in the subquery?  I don't understand why it can't just be `select count(*)`.

Comment: Basically yes. `hostname` in the subquery is for joining with the main table.

Comment: How would I extend this to query only rows that have a `count` greater than a given number?

Comment: Add `where count > 10` at the end.